# Localizar arquivo que gerou erro CSRF TOKEN

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, csrf

Configurei o arquivo `handler` para sempre que ocorrer algum erro no servidor, eu receba um e-mail com os detalhes.

Então hoje recebi um e-mail com o seguinte erro:

> array(3) { ["message"]=> string(0) "" ["file"]=> string(104)
>   "/var/www/infochat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(71) }

Eu sei o que é esse erro, mas o problema é que eu não sei o que causou, ou seja, qual arquivo ou código que foi o responsável, para eu poder corrigir.

Não encontrei nada nos logs (posso ter visto o log errado). Teria algum lugar que eu possa checar para descobrir?